# apply(list) to multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have a `dataframe` that looks like this :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,1,2,2,2,2,3],
                   'B':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'],
                   'C':['1','2','3','4','5','6','7']})
```

`df2 = df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(list).reset_index()` produces this :

```
   A             B
0  1        [a, b]
1  2  [c, d, e, f]
2  3           [g]
```

How can I produce this?

```
   A             B            C
0  1        [a, b]       [1, 2]
1  2  [c, d, e, f] [3, 4, 5, 6]
2  3           [g]          [7]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this

```py
df.groupby('A', as_index=False).agg(B=("B", list), C=("C", list))
```

```
   A             B             C
0  1        [a, b]        [1, 2]
1  2  [c, d, e, f]  [3, 4, 5, 6]
2  3           [g]           [7]
```

Or equivalently

```
pd.pivot_table(data=df, index="A", values=["B", "C"], aggfunc=list).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
df.groupby('A', as_index=False).agg(list)
```

This gives you:

```
   A             B             C
0  1        [a, b]        [1, 2]
1  2  [c, d, e, f]  [3, 4, 5, 6]
2  3           [g]           [7]
```

Comment: This a good answer ... I should have mentioned that I wanted to explicitly specify the columns for the result.  @creanion answer seems to handle that

Comment: Okay... so you can be explicit with the columns, eg: `df.groupby('A', as_index=False)[['B', 'C']].agg(list)`